# Load LWC Spinner Until Component is Completely Rendered

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Im working on implementing a spinner in a modal similar to the idea presented here:

https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1400/1*wTsQQXX5jjlFtUu8uu1u0A.gif

I would like the spinner to spin until the elements of the component are completely rendered. Most of the examples I have seen are focused on getting data from the Server but in this case i'm waiting for the elements to load and switch between templates

The below code is the HTML example from the link above which is what I would aim to do but there is no associated js file. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="SpinnerExample">
    
    <!-- Using the if:true directive we will conditionaly show/hide the spinner -->
    <div if:true={isLoading} style="height: 200px; position:relative">
      <lightning-spinner variant="base" size="medium"></lightning-spinner>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Using the if:false directive we will conditionaly show/hide the picklists -->
    <div if:false={isLoading} class="slds-m-around_large">
      <p class="slds-m-bottom_small">Picklist options have been loaded.</p>
      <lightning-combobox options={picklistOptions.picklistOne} label="PicklistOne" placeholder="Select value"></lightning-combobox>
      <lightning-combobox options={picklistOptions.picklistTwo} label="PicklistTwo" placeholder="Select value"></lightning-combobox>
      <lightning-combobox options={picklistOptions.picklistThree} label="PicklistThree" placeholder="Select value"></lightning-combobox>
    </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

For reference I was using this article: https://bootcamp.uxdesign.cc/lightning-web-component-spinner-the-complete-guide-903b77c02e34

Comment: Please try to hide the spinner in the `renderredCallback` of the root component or simply use the `setTimeout()` with a few seconds delay.